# jquery , images, selector

Tags: jquery, html, image

a I have some images on page and  I want to put `<span>` tag bellow each images, with 'alt' text , with jQuery

I began with :

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='images/1.jpg' alt='text1' />
    <img src='images/2.jpg' alt='text2' />
    <img src='images/3.jpg' alt='text3' />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".container img").after("<span>"+$(".container img").attr('alt')+"</span>");
```

but It puts to all `<span>` the first alt

I need to Obtain :

```
 <div class='container'>
        <img src='images/1.jpg' alt='text1' />
        <span>text1</span>
        <img src='images/2.jpg' alt='text2' />
        <span>text2</span>
        <img src='images/3.jpg' alt='text3' />
        <span>text3</span>
    </div>
```

I need to put it in array ?? Or other ideas ??

Help me please, Thank You !!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)

```
$(".container img").each(function() {
    $(this).after("<span>"+$(this).attr('alt')+"</span>");
});
```

or a little nicer (in my opinion)

```
$(".container img").each(function() {
    $(this).after($("<span/>").text($(this).attr('alt')));
});
```